# sbt.IO.copyFile / sbt.IO.copyDirectory executable flag

Tags: scala, sbt

When I copy a file or a folder with `sbt.IO.copyFile` or `sbt.IO.copyDirectory` then the executable flags on the files are discarded. Is there any way around this with the sbt helper function or do I have to use the basic Java copy functions?

Comment: Seems [copyFile](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/util/io/src/main/scala/sbt/IO.scala#L580) copy only contents of file.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```scala
java.nio.file.Files.copy(Path source, Path target, CopyOption... options)
```

For example if you have fromdos in current directory:

```
scala> import java.nio.file._
import java.nio.file._

scala> Files.copy(Paths.get("fromdos"),Paths.get("copyFromDos"),StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES)
res0: java.nio.file.Path = copyFromDos
```

See [Java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) or [Java 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...%29) documentation for more details.

*Copy dir*

```
def copyDir(source: Path, dest: Path) {
    Files.copy(source, dest, StandardCopyOption.COPY_ATTRIBUTES)
    if (source.toFile.isDirectory) {
      val dir = source.toFile
      dir.listFiles.foreach(file =>
        copyDir(file.toPath, dest.resolve(file.getName)))
    }
  }
```